# Topic modeling - How to get different sub-topics from a single topic

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I'm working with around 8k documents and all of them are based on a single topic. However, the documents cover various different events that happened across the world, related to that single topic. I want to find these subtopics (or events) from the documents. Now to achieve this, I'm using the gensim LDA model:

```
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in docTrain]

model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, num_topics=17, chunksize=10000, id2word=dictionary,random_state=123, alpha = 0.01, eta = 0.9, passes = 10 )

coherencemodel = gensim.models.CoherenceModel(model=model, texts=data, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='c_v')
```

Since I was unaware of the number of topics in this case, I used elbow method to determine the optimal number of topics in this case, which comes out to be 17 or 18. Also, the coherence score is not increasing beyond 0.4.

I want to know what is going wrong and if there is any other approach that would help me solve this problem in a better way. Please let me know if any other information regarding my approach is required.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Have you manually reviewed the topics created, and found they don't make sense, or aren't useful? Is there a reason you're using a non-default `alpha=0.01` value, and a non-default `eta=0.9` value, and if so are you sure those are improving your results?

Comment: @gojomo The topics generated do make sense and are useful to some extent. However, the coherence score is not increasing. I tried using the non default parameters `alpha` and `eta` for improving the coherence score, but I dont think they're really making any difference to the results.

Comment: Well, those values look so different from the usual defaults that I'd expect them to hurt rather than help, unless.until seeing data/reasoning otherwise.

Comment: @gojomo I tried changing them to default, but the coherence score doesn't show any improvements. Could you suggest something here?

Comment: If your topics seem to make sense & work for your purposes, the absolute value of the coherence score may not be that important. If that score and/or informal eyeball evaluations don't show any benefit for your non-default settings, I'd stick with defaults until you can prove changing them helps for your data & goals. If all parameter tweaks can't help, the main problem may be a deficiency in your data - so "find/try more data" may be the best course.